# Two dryer vent connections in the laundry room

Tags: dryer

We just bought a new house recently. I was hooking up the dryer and noticed I have what appear to be two dryer vent connections in the wall. One was labeled "vent" and the other was capped. I'm  curious, does anyone know what the second connection is for?

Comment: Is this a "new" new house, or just new to you? Can you locate where the vents go to on the outside? some photos of the inside and outside area may help.

Comment: It's new new. So I figured some things out. Now I'm just wondering why...I popped the cap off to see where the second connection ran and both vent connections terminate to the same tube and run to the roof. It doesn't make sense to me why you would have to connections instead of just one.

Comment: Could be for a stacked hookup or a side by side really hard to say without a photo.

Comment: Can you provide a picture? If these are within inches of one another than it's strange but if they're 20 feet apart then they did it for homeowner convenience so that you're not running a 20 foot sagging dryer vent from wherever you decide to install your dryer. Also, see https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6166/42053

Comment: It's not a common thing, so to be able to answer we'd need more information. Pictures at a minimum

Comment: Hello.........considering adding pictures and additional information as requested because this question is ripe for being closed as it currently sits unanswerable.

Comment: Yes, can you please post photos of your configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the second capped dryer vent is a cleanout particularly if it is located in an area where it would NOT be covered by the dryer.  My guess is that the capped vent is beside the dryer and exposed while the vent opening is behind where the dryer would go.  The push today is to use fixed steel piping not the flexible junk since the plastic flex junk has been known to catch on fire when plugged up.  That means dragging the dryer out to get it out of the way is a major production involving contortions and likely at least once dropping a screwdriver behind the dryer while fumbling with the clamps.  It would be much easier to just remove a cap and stuff your vent pipe vacuum up into it and leave the dryer be.

But since this is a brand new house why don't you just ask the builder?